# Intellij - Spring Retry @Recover method marked as unused

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-retry, unused-functions

When using Spring Retry @Recover method (which works ok) IntelliJ always marking method as unused and suggest to safe delete

```
@Recover
public void recover(RetryableException e, String param1) {
    //recover
}
@Retryable(include = RetryableException.class, maxAttempts = 2)
public void retryable(String param1) {
    //execute
    throw new RetryableException();
}
```

> Method 'recover(com.gth.common.exceptions.RetryableException, java.lang.String)' is never used

How can it be avoided? how can IntelliJ be aware of the recover method usage?

- I don't want IntelliJ to stop warn about `Unused declaration`, only the false positive warnings

Comment: Can you confirm that this code is actually invoked? If so, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrey code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method declarations looks ok but as you haven't shared any further details, it is mostly because you are not throwing `RetryableException` from your `retryable` method.

To invoke recovery after retries, your retry must throw type of exception which you have defined as `recover` method's argument. Please check about that , if that is not case, please share some more details.

Edit:

Spring's recovery method gets called internally after retry & hence after scanning code, intellij didn't find any reference where your `recover` is getting called.

This is just warning from intellij & don't pose any issue. You can disable this behaviour from `Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Unused Declaration >Java > Unused declaration` .

Other option is to use `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` above your `recover`.

Comment: it's just sample code, I'm throwing RetryableException , I'll update, the issue is Intellij not knowing that recover method is executed through spring retry mechanism

Comment: I don't want Intellij to stop warn about `Unused declaration`, only the false positive warnings

Comment: edited answer, you can use `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` specific to this method as  a workaround